# Why meta.gps.gpsLatitude is null?

Tags: dart, flutter, gps, metadata

I use the multi_image_picker library (1) and i get a List of Asset. 
I need the metadata for each image so i  do (2) but always the result of **{meta.gps.gpsLatitude}** and **{meta.gps.gpsLongitude}** is null. I know that code is fine because **{meta.gps.gpsLatitudeRef}** and **{meta.gps.gpsLongitudeRef}** is correct.

I just need the Long and Lat for each image if you know other form for do this is welcome.

1) I tried pass Asset to File and use exif but i can´t
2) I read Metadata and Multi Image Picker class but it does not say anything

Multi Image Picker class:
https://sh1d0w.github.io/multi_image_picker/#/androudtroubleshooting

Metadata class:
https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/multi_image_picker/latest/multi_image_picker/Metadata-class.html

```
(1)
Future <void> loadAssets() async{
    setState(() {
     images = List<Asset>(); 
    });
    List<Asset> resultList = List<Asset>();
    String error = 'No hay error';
    try{
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
        maxImages: 50, 
        enableCamera: true,
        //options: CupertinoOptions(takePhotoIcon: "chat"),
      );
    }
    on PlatformException  catch (e){
      error = e.message; 
    }
    if (!mounted) return ;
    setState(() {
     images = resultList; 
     _error = error;
     modList(resultList);
    });
  }
```

```
(2)
  modList(List resultList) async{
    for (var x=0 ; x < resultList.length; x++){
      Asset asset = resultList[x];
      Metadata meta = await asset.requestMetadata();
      print ("Ref Altitud:${meta.gps.gpsLatitudeRef} Latitud : ${meta.gps.gpsLatitude}" ); 
      print ("Ref Longitud:${meta.gps.gpsLongitudeRef} Longitud : ${meta.gps.gpsLongitude}" );
    } 
  }
```